# Object to xml mapping formated as spring bean definition

Tags: java, spring, xml-serialization

I am looking for a way to serialize java object into XML in format same as spring bean defination. For example, the class defined as:

```
package x.y.z;
class foo {
    String name;
    int counter;

    ...setter and getter omitted for simplicity ....
}
```

object of class foo will be serialized to:

```
<bean id="" class="x.y.z.foo">
   <property name="name" value="some random value"/>
   <property name="counter" value="1" />
</bean>
```

The purpose is that later on I can inject the objects into unit test by copy/paste the xml to spring context file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with annotations, something like Simple XML Serialization can do something like what you are looking for.  I also like XStream, but it may not give itself to an XML that is as different from the class structure as yours is.

http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php

You might actually be better off just writing a marshal() even a dirty one with a string buffer like this:

```
public Element marshal() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("\t<bean id="">\n");
        sb.append("\t\t<property name=\"").append(name).append(""/>\n");
    sb.append("\t</bean>\n");
    InputStream istream = new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Document myDoc = new SAXBuilder().build(istream);
}
```

or a better one building up a Document and adding elements.

then output it

```
    // Save it to a file:
    XMLOutputter out = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    java.io.FileWriter writer = new java.io.FileWriter(fileName);
    out.output(document, writer);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

I think you might spend more time trying to configure an XML Serializer than you would just hacking one out if your schema is so simple, but different than your XML.